# Apple Photos: can I force it to treat 'burst' photos as separate items?

Tags: photos

I like the 'burst' feature in my iPhone for taking photos in low light conditions: it increases the chance of there being at least one photo without motion blur.

However, Apple Photos insists on treating these bursts as a group, which is really annoying. 
My workflow:

1. take photos
2. import them
3. find the best photo of the burst
4. throw away all the others

Photos makes 3. and 4 needlessly difficult by forcing you into a separate interface for step 3. When you're done selecting a photo, it pretends to throw away the non-selected photos, but when I export the result I still end up with 10 photo files instead of 1.

I'd rather have all 10 photos available as separate items.

I'm using Photos 1.0.1.