# Make Photos recognize several separate photos as a Burst?

Tags: photos, import

I am importing several photos from an external source (ex. a non-iPhone camera, or in my case, variants of a digital painting) and would like Photos.app to treat them as a "burst" photo, because I like the UI for bursts, and it would help to keep my photo library & albums clean. Is there any way for me to "teach" Photos that the photos I've just imported should be considered as one burst, instead of being 6+ totally independent photos?

I'm basically looking for the opposite of ["Can I force [Photos] to treat 'burst' photos as separate items?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/357266/).